# how to get params in route.ts file in next js 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to update a post. This is the file structure: `/api/posts/[postId]/route.ts`. how can i get the `postId` in `PATCH` function in `route.ts` file?

```
// PATCH api/posts/3
export const PATCH = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
    // get the `postId` somehow
}
```

I tried `req.nextUrl.searchParams()`, but it only select query params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const PATCH = async (
  request: Request,
  { params }: { params: { postId: string } }
) => {
  const postId = params.postId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static getOptionById = (
    req: Request
  ) => {
    const optionId = req.params['id']; 
    ...
  }
```

in the router:

```
OptionRouter.get("/getOptionById/:id", OptionsController.getOptionById);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).